# I can't draw a circle in my canvas within my square

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem, I am French and I don't speak English very well.
So I explain you the problem:
I draw a canvas in js composed of 6 rows and 7 columns then I try to draw a circle in it with a click event.
However I can't manage to position in the canvas the circle click well proportioned inside.
I tried to get the position of the mouse click to then position my circle in the square, I failed.
Then I changed my strategy, I tried to store the canvas in a table then try to push in the square of the canvas the circle, imagining that it is positioned in the limits of the square of my canvas but again failed.

```
javascript
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('grille');
const ccc = canvas.getContext('2d');
let i = 0,l = 0;
let x = 10,y = 10;
let tabC = [];
let tabtab = [];
let cnvx = -40,cnvy = 560;
let posiX = 0,posiY = 0;
let test;
// fonction dessine caneva
(function (){
        for (l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
            for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                tabtab.push(ccc.strokeRect(x, y, 100, 100));
                tabC.push('');
                x += 100;
            }
            y += 100;
            x = 10;
        }console.log("tabtab : "+tabtab);
})();

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    posiX = e.offsetX;
    posiY = e.offsetY;
    console.log((e.offsetX)+ ' , ' + (e.offsetY));
    for (let j = 0;j<tabC.length;j++){
        if (tabC[j]===''){
            tabC.push('0');
            ccc.beginPath();
            ccc.fillStyle = 'red';
            tabtab.push(ccc.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY , 40, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI));
            ccc.fill();
            ccc.closePath();
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToUbg.png)

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: strokeRect and arc do not return anything, they only place some pixels on the canvas. You are filling tabtab with undefined values. To place circles within the square, you must calculate where the nearest square would be. This information is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Indeed, I will try to store the dimension of each square in a table and then calculate by the position of the cursor to determine the click if it is in the surface of the square and then think of drawing the circle. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example that places circles in a grid by [calculating their grid coordinate](https://jsfiddle.net/b0Lyqegs/).

It converts the pixel coordinate of the click into a grid square by applying the math.floor function to subtracting the top corner of the grid and dividing by the size of the grid:

```
  let gridX = Math.floor((mouseX - startX) / gridSize);
  let gridY = Math.floor((mouseY - startY) / gridSize);
```

It then calculates the center of that grid square by converting the grid coordinate back to a pixel coordinate and adding half the size of the grid square

```
  let pixelX = startX + gridX * gridSize + gridSize / 2;
  let pixelY = startY + gridY * gridSize + gridSize / 2;
```

As a bonus, I've also added an array that keeps track of which squares have been filled, gridState. Squares that have been filled will be true, others will be false.

Comment: I thank you for your time, you inspired me I did not copy you but I succeeded in calculating each pixel of the canvas :)